# Error Code with ggplot in R

Tags: r

I have uninstalled R and Rstudio.  When I originally downloaded Rstudio the package was not listed in the packages section, so I downloaded and imported the zip file.  There is no current version of R that is 3.3.0 that I can find-- my R version is 3.2.2.  I have tried to install using the RGui as admin and I get the same error.

This is my error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) :    there is no package called ‘gtable’ In addition: Warning
>   message: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.3.0  Error:
>   package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are somehow executing R 3.3.0. No matter, though, you can simply invoke `install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com', type='source')` should sort you. If not, post a comment.

Comment: Added the command line and this is what I got.   

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.3.0 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
> install.package('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com', type=source)
Error: could not find function "install.package"

Comment: Additionally, > detach("package:ggplot2", unload=TRUE)
Error in detach("package:ggplot2", unload = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'name' argument
> install.package('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com', type=source)
Error: could not find function "install.package

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.  After reading your command, I went directly through the repository install via Rstudio and that worked as well.